# Elasticsearch Error - call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: magento2, category, composer, elasticsearch

I have an M2 with Elasticsearch installed, with the Smile/Elasticsuite module.

These are my versions in composer.json:

```
"smile/elasticsuite": "2.5.15",
"elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^2.2.3"
```

And in all the category pages, I have this error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in /vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-virtual-category/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php on line 153

There are the two lines related with this error :

```
$virtualRule = $category->getVirtualRule();
$data = call_user_func_array([$virtualRule, $callback], [$category]);
```

Somehow, the `$virtualRule` variable is NULL, and the function `call_user_func_array` doesn't like this if someone already saw this thing.

Feel free to answer, thanks!

Comment: Also, what Magento version are you using?

Comment: I am on 2.2.5, but now it's working with theses versions : 
"elasticsearch/elasticsearch" : "5.3.2" 

"smile/elasticsuite" : "2.6.2" 

and elasticsearch local (with brew) now on version 5.6.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed **ElasticSearch** version is "`number`" : "`2.2.3`". In order to make it work with Magento 2.2.x and ElasticSuite 2.5.x you need to install **ElasticSearch 6.x**. Make sure to install the correct version of ElasticSearch.

I am actually using Elasticsearch 5.x series and it seems to be working with no issues.

My `curl` result:

```
{
  "name" : "ARXtHgF",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "0L1pnmTiQBaWL21J5p5iPw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.6.12",
    "build_hash" : "cfe3d9f",
    "build_date" : "2018-09-10T20:12:43.732Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Alright thanks I'll try, what is your Magento version btw ? And you have no problem with reindexing ? Cause when I use ElasticSuite 2.6.x, I don't have the issue above on my category page, but I'm unable to complete the reindex because of this :
`No handler for type [text] declared on field [search]`

Comment: I am using Magento 2.2.4. Also, I had the same problem when trying to reindex (`No handler for type [text] declared on field [search]`) and when upgraded the Elasticsearch, the error was gone ;)

Comment: oh ! you upgraded to which version precisely ? I have 5.3.2 now and I still have the reindexing problem :/

Comment: I have 5.6.12  and it's working with no issues ;) Do you get the same error when running `bin/magento setup:upgrade`?

Comment: oh you're talking about you're Elasticsearch on your machine ! I was talking about my composer version, which is v5.3.2 and the next one available after that is v6.0.0. Anyway, I don't have this issue when I use the "upgrade" command, and on my machine (the number version when I use the curl command) is 2.4.6, I think I should upgrade this one too ! 
But just to be sure, can you tell me exactly your composer version of `elasticsearch/elasticsearch` and `smile/elasticsuite` please :)

Comment: What Magento version are you using?

Comment: I was on 2.2.4, and now I upgraded it to 2.2.5 !

Comment: Ahh I see, You need to upgrade your ElasticSuite to ElasticSuite 2.6.x latest release. With (preferably Elasticsearch 6.x). I run Magento 2.2.4 with ElasticSuite 2.6 and Elasticsearch 5.6.12 ;)

Comment: It's working !! Thanks a lot @Bare Feet
`"elasticsearch/elasticsearch" : "5.3.2"`

 `"smile/elasticsuite" : "2.6.2"`

and elasticsearch local (with brew) now on version `5.6.12`

Comment: Great! I'm glad you managed to get it working :) Accept the answer to keep the community clean :)